# Ending with a for loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop, syntax

I am experiencing a bit of confusion with how to place a for loop at the end of a line in python, for instance

```
for i in x:
    print i
```

produces the expected result but if I run

```
print i for i in x
```

I get a syntax error. Could someone explain a little more about how one goes about putting your for loops at the end of a line like this.

Comment: As several answers have pointed out, if you tell us what you're trying to do there may be a better way to help. If you're honestly trying to print all the items from an iterable, `for i in x: print i` is the clearest and most explicit way to do that.

Comment: In Python 3, `print(i for i in x)`, since `print` is now a function.

Comment: @Will that will give you some lovely output like `<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f2d794b5500>`

Comment: @wim, oops, make it into a list: ``print(list(i for i in x))``.

Comment: no, that is equivalent to printing `list(x)` or `[i for i in x]` which is something else.

Comment: Sure, but I thought it might do what the OP intended with something close to the desired syntax.

Comment: @ejl360: you're supposed to pick the best answer and accept it, just FYI :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In earlier versions of Python, the idea of list comprehensions was introduced to neaten up these two patterns of code:

```
# Go through each item in a list and run a test on them
# build a new list containing only items that pass the test

results = []
for item in somelist:
    if sometest(item):
        results.add(item)

and

# build a new list by changing every item in a list in the
# same way

results = []
for item in somelist:
    results.add(2 * item)
```

by adding a new syntax that includes doing all three things in one - changing the items and/or testing them to only include some in the result, and creating the list of the results:

```
results = [2 * item for item in somelist if sometest(item)]
# results is a list
```

This feature uses the [] syntax that indicates "list" in Python, and it builds a list right away in memory.

Sometimes you don't want or need the entire list built in memory right away, so later versions of Python introduced generator expressions - the same idea, but they save memory by quickly returning a generator which you can iterate over as if it was a list, and it builds the list as and when you use it.

But they can't have the same syntax and be a direct swap out because they behave slightly differently, so they use () instead of [], e.g.:

```
somelist = [1,2,3,4,5]
results = (2 * item for item in somelist if sometest(item))
# results is a generator
```

If you try and call a function with this, you get two layers of parentheses:

```
function((2 * item for item in somelist))
```

Which looks silly, so you can leave one out:

```
function(2 * item for item in somelist)
```

Which *appears* to be a standalone backwards `for` loop on its own, but it actually isn't.

So with parentheses you *can* write *this*:

```
>>> print (item for item in [1,2,3])
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fe31b8663c0>
```

Which is the closest thing to what you *wrote* that is valid syntax in Python 2.x, but it doesn't do what you expect, and ^^ is what it does and why.

Or *this*:

```
>>> print [item for item in [1,2,3]]
[1,2,3]
```

Which generates a list and prints the list, the other close thing to what you wrote, but still not what you expected.

-- (there really isn't much point in me posting now a bunch other answers have appeared while I was writing this, but eh).

Comment: Love your answer! Much more complete than mine. Throw in my note about the starred genexp printing (more or less) as expected and I'll toss mine

Comment: @adsmith thanks :).  I'm not Python 3 enough to know about the starred genexp printing and be comfortable with what it's doing, and I don't want to just copy your answer into mine. Besides you have comments too. I'll upvote you

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You've probably seen a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions), which takes the form `x for x in iter`. a `for` loop is slightly different, though you can definitely see `for x in iter` inside the genexp.

In Python3, you can do:

```
print(*(i for i in x))
```

And as @wim points out in the comments, you can make it more "`for` loopy" by doing

```
print(*(i for i in x), sep='\n')
```

You can of course do arbitrary changes since this is a genexp, so e.g. `i**2 for i in x` will give you the square of each item in `x`, `i for i in x if i%2` will give all odd numbers in `x`, etc.

This will create a generator of each item in `x`, then pass each one in turn (using the `*` assignment the same way `*args` is built and etc) as separate arguments to `print`

Comment: Is that any different from `print(*x)`?

Comment: @wim not if you're using it as written, but since it's a genexp you can do `print(*(i for i in x if condition))` or etc.

Comment: Ah yes.  You might want to add `sep='\n'` to make it more equivalent to the for loop, but +1 anyway.

Answer (score 1):

First of all:

1. this is considered **bad style**—you're essentially just abusing the list comprehension syntax to get what's effectively a different notation for imperative for loops.
2. this only works in Python 3 where `print` is a function by default, or when you do `from __future__ import print_function` in Python 2.x

However, if you insist on putting the `for ...` part after the `print i` part, you can do:

```
[print(i) for i in x]
```

(but I'm writing that example for purely "academic" purposes)

**P.S.** if you let us know what you want to do, we might be able to provide a suitable overall solution, but if you're just asking for the sake of it, then that's it.

Comment: I was about to downvote for using side-effects, then read the rest of your post and noticed that you strongly advised not to do this for that exact reason. +1

Answer (score 1):

*expression* for i in x

doesn't mean anything by itself in Python. You can have

(*expression* for i in x)

[*expression* for i in x]

But you can't do

```
[print i for i in x]
```

because print isn't an expression, it's a statement.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of that is equivalent in python 2.x would be this:

```
print '\n'.join(str(i) for i in x)
```

But don't do that.  The for loop as you had it is much clearer.

If you are just fooling around in interactive interpreter and want to one-liner it for some reason, this will work:

```
for i in x: print i
```

But it's violating pep8 so I wouldn't write a line like that into a script.

Comment: For other readers, I went looking to see which part of PEP 8 (the Python code style guide) it violates, and the guide is here: http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#other-recommendations and in section *Whitespace: Other Recommendations* it says *"Compound statements (multiple statements on the same line) are generally discouraged"*.